# Azure blob with object replication as an event grid source

Tags: azure, azure-storage, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-queues, azure-eventgrid

Is azure [blob object replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/object-replication-overview) creating [blob storage events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview)?

The use case is to replicate blobs between azure regions/subscriptions. When the blob arrives at the target storage account, Snowpipe should be notify via event grid and storage queue ([as in here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-azure.html)).

After setting object replication, event grid and queue, I can see files arriving, but no event seems to be generated. Only if I manually delete a blob or create one, events are pushed to queue.
My first guess is that object replication is not creating event, but maybe there is another issue with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.

Have a look of this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#list-of-events-for-blob-rest-apis

> Triggered when a blob is created or replaced. Specifically, this event
> is triggered when clients use the PutBlob, PutBlockList, or CopyBlob
> operations that are available in the Blob REST API.

I use copy blob azure cli:

```
az storage blob copy start --destination-blob 1120.png --destination-container test1 --account-key Oczxxxxxx== --account-name 0730bowmanwindow --source-account-key Oczxxxxxx== --source-account-name 0730bowmanwindow --source-blob 1120.png --source-container test
```

And the Event grid get the event:

[image]

This  is the filters on my side:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bowman-zhu, but it seems to me that you haven't read my question carefully enough. It was not about copying blobs, but about using blob object replication feature.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry for misunderstand your question. I did a test, and indeed, as you said, blob object replication did not generate events. I think this may be a bug. This should be understood as an action to create a blob and the creation event should be generated. Tomorrow I will feedback this issue to the microsoft. Your findings are meaningful and thanks for your contribution!:) (You may still be unable to receive events until this bug is fixed.)

Comment: Thanks @bowman-shu - could you post here a link to the support request/bug, to track the work on fix. Or at least share the feedback.

Comment: @Marcin I have post the issue here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/66572 If you want to feedback, this is the link: https://feedback.azure.com/